# Load markers from database in Leaflet

Tags: laravel, leaflet, maps, laravel-blade

In Laravel's view blade I pulled the data from the database and made a table.

```
<table id="companies" class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Companies</th>
                <th>Devices</th>
                <th>X</th>
                <th>Y</th>
                <th>Time</th>
                <th>Vehicles</th>
                <th>Drivers</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        </p>
        <tbody>
        @foreach ($satwork as $row)

            <tr>
                <td>{{ $row -> company_name}}</td>
                <td>{{ $row -> device_type}}</td>
                <td>{{ $row -> x}}</td>
                <td>{{ $row -> y}}</td>
                <td>{{ $row -> datetime}}</td>
                <td>{{ $row -> license_plate}}</td>
                <td>{{ $row -> driver_name}}</td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

In Leaflet I have code that pulling data from DB via that table, and show it on map.

```
var koordinate = {!! json_encode($device->toArray()) !!};
    console.log(koordinate);

    for (var i=0; i < koordinate.length; i++) {
        if(koordinate[i].x && koordinate[i].y){
        var marker = L.marker([koordinate[i].x, koordinate[i].y])
        .bindPopup("Device: "+koordinate[i].device_type+'<br>' + "Time: "+koordinate[i].time)

        .addTo(map);
        }
    }
```

I need a way how to pull all the data directly from the database to Leaflet, without contact with view blade. Is that even posible?

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you can use a javascript HTTP-request to for example an API that returns all data.

You can use the build-in API functionality of Laravel, and create a new route in `routes/api.php` that returns all data, do note that this way, others may also be able to fetch this data, which means you have to make sure to protect your data somehow.

Since I always use JQuery in my projects, I use the JQuery `getJSON()` method to fetch all data, and then display it using javascript.

Maybe something like this could work? (I haven't tested this):

```
    var mapboxTiles = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/examples.map-i87786ca/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '<a href="http://www.mapbox.com/about/maps/" target="_blank">Terms &amp; Feedback</a>'
    });

    var map = L.map('map')
        .addLayer(mapboxTiles)
        .setView([42.444508, -76.499491], 12);

    // THIS IS NEW
    var promise = $.getJSON("businesses.json");
    promise.then(function(data) {
      data.forEach(koordinate => {
        if(koordinate[i].x && koordinate[i].y){
           var marker = L.marker([koordinate[i].x, koordinate[i].y])
             .bindPopup("Device: "+koordinate[i].device_type+'<br>' + "Time: "+koordinate[i].time).addTo(map);
        }
      })
    });
```

Sourced from http://bl.ocks.org/zross/40d24941a46bff313c65

Comment: I newer worked with json before, can I make it from controller?

Comment: In your `routes/api.php`, you can create a new route, just like in `routes/web.php` which returns a response. But instead of returing a view, you can return something like `return Koordinate::all()`, where Koordinate is your model class name. This will then be converted to JSON format.

Comment: I found some tutorial where I have to make Resources. But I'll try both examples